# how can I verify that dead code was stripped from the binary?

Tags: xcode, linux, macos, unix

My c/obj-c code (an iOS app built with clang) has some functions excluded by `#ifdefs`. I want to make sure that code that gets called from those functions, but not from others (dead code) gets stripped out (eliminated) at link time.
I tried:

1. Adding a local literal char[] in a function that should be eliminated; the string is still visible when running `strings` on the executable.
2. Adding a function that should be eliminated; the function name is still visible when running strings.

Before you ask, I'm building for release, and all strip settings (including dead-code stripping, obviously) are enabled.

The question is not really xcode/apple/iOS specific; I assume the answer should be pretty much the same on any POSIX development platform.

Comment: Are the functions in question defined as `static`? They have to be, or else the compiler has to leave them in in case some other code from a different object file wants to call them.

Comment: No they are not static, but my point is elimination *at link time*. The linker DOES know if they are used or not.

Comment: Sounds to me like you've got a project on your hands...Usually, the linker simply takes everything that's in the object file and fixes it up.  If you want Whole Program Optimization (and dead code elimination can be regarded as an optimization), then you need to look at whether the work in GCC will help at all, and, failing that, you can always write it yourself.  The compiler will help if the unused functions are static.  If they can't be static, then you'll get them included in the executable.  You'll need to be more careful with your conditional code if you want the unused eliminated.

Comment: @noamtm The GNU toolchain has never been able to remove parts of object files at link time until VERY recently. [That feature is now available](http://gcc.gnu.org/wiki/LinkTimeOptimization) but it isn't yet in widespread use. You are probably not using it. It's also not simple: it relies on having the compiler write a bunch of extra information into the object file which the linker then uses.

Comment: Dead code elimination is supported in the llvm-based iOS toolchain; in fact, when I turn it off the final binary *does* get larger. But it doesn't seem to remove the things I wrote above.

Comment: @Celada the LTO is rather recent feature, but AFAIU removing unused objects doesn't really require a fully-fledged LTO.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**(EDIT)**

In binutils, `ld` has the `--gc-sections` option which does what you want for sections on object level. You have several options:

- use `gcc`'s flags `-ffunction-sections` and `-fdata-sections` to isolate each symbol into its own section, then use `--gc-sections`;
- put **all** candidates for removal into a separate file and the linker will be able to strip the whole section;
- disassemble the resulting binary, remove dead code, assemble again;
- use `strip` with appropriate `-N` options to discard the offending symbols from the 
  symbol table - this will leave the code and data there, but it won't show up in the symbol table.

Comment: I am not familiar with that option, but I just read about it and I don't think it will do what the OP wants. It seems to be only for removing ENTIRE unused sections (like `.text`, `.bss`, etc...) but in this case we want to eliminate certain functions (mainly in `.text`) while keeping others (which are also mainly in `.text`).

Comment: Thanks. I'll check if the llvm/clang toolchain used in iOS supports these options.